# Unable to generate and show randomly generated integers

Tags: javascript, function, math, random

I'm a student and have been attempting to create a program in JavaScript to create a function and generate a random integer (whole number) between 1 and 9. I have created two different programs for this in my testing but while using Visual Studio Code it doesn't print the generated number.

Please see code below and if you have any questions please let me know.

```
function random_num() {
    let random_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) +1;
    return random_num;
}
console.log(random_num);
```

```
function random_num(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(1);
    max = Math.floor(9);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
console.log(random_num);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to call your function - more info can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#calling_functions)

Comment: console.log(random_num()) will call output what the function returns. console.log(random_num) will output the function definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Always save your result in variable then print it
```

```js
function random_num(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(1);
    max = Math.floor(9);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

const randomNumber1 = random_num()
console.log(randomNumber1);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fhhu4.png)

```js
'use strict';

function random_num() {
    let random_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) +1;
    return random_num;
}

const randomNumber = random_num()
console.log(randomNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the first snippet will end up giving a number between 1 and 9 which is the exact thing you wanted but the problem is that you are not calling the function itself. So this should help.

```
 console.log(random_num())
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get the result of functions that return a value.
Here is the solution:

```
console.log(random_num());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions, your answers have helped fix this for me! I'm just learning JavaScript so this help was greatly appreciated!

```
function random_num(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(1);
    max = Math.floor(9);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

const randomNumber1 = random_num()
console.log(randomNumber1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, you need to be outputting your result somewhere, no? Online scripting environments have spoiled us a bit in recent years, but when you're doing thins locally, never assume your build assumes implicit return.